# Solve quadratic; learning functions; program doesn't return values

Tags: c, function

Please, take a look at the program I wrote as part of the assignment after chapter 7 Programming in C. The program should return roots of a quadratic based on values of constants typed in by the user. The program should be very simple; I am at the beginner's level.
Although the compiler does compile the program, the only output I get is the prompting message. But after I enter three values, nothing happens, the program ends, and I am back at my Terminal. 
I have edited the program. And now if I enter some values that make discriminant less than 0, I get

```
Please, enter three constants of the quadratic:   
1 2 3
Roots are imaginary
Square roots of this quadratic are:
```

Thus the main function statement still appears.

If I enter other values, I get

```
Please, enter three constants of the quadratic:   
1 8 2
-0.256970 and -7.743030Square roots of this quadratic are:
```

Do you see this formatting? Why does this happen?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float abs_value (float x);
float approx_sqrt (float x);
float solve_quadratic (float a, float b, float c);

// The main function prompts the user for 3 constant values to fill a quadratic
// ax^2 + bx + c
int main(void)
{
    float a, b, c;

    printf("Please, enter three constants of the quadratic:   \n");

    if (scanf ("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c) == 3)
        printf("Square roots of this quadratic are:  \n", solve_quadratic(a,b,c));

    return 0;
}

// Function to take an absolute value of x that is used further in square root function
float abs_value (float x)
{
    if (x < 0)
        x = - x;
    return x;
}

// Function to compute an approximate square root - Newton Raphson method
float approx_sqrt (float x)
{
    float guess = 1;

    while (abs_value (pow(guess,2) / x) > 1.001 || abs_value (pow(guess,2) / x) < 0.999)
          guess = (x / guess + guess) / 2.0;

    return guess;
}

// Function to find roots of a quadratic
float solve_quadratic (float a, float b, float c)
{
    float x1, x2;
    float discriminant = pow(b,2) - 4 * a * c;

    if (discriminant < 0)
    {
        printf("Roots are imaginary\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        x1 = (-b + approx_sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
        x2 = (-b - approx_sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
    }

    return x1, x2;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This is a REALLY good time to buckle down and learn a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (scanf ("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c) == 1)
```

`scanf` returns the number of arguments succesfully scanned.  In this case, you want it to be 3, not 1.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
return x1, x2;
```

does not return two values. That line is equivalent to:

```
x1;  // Nothing happens.
return x2;
```

If you want to be able to return two values, create a `struct` and return an instance of the `struct`.

```
typedef struct pair { float x1; float x2;} pair;

// Change the return type of solve_quadratic 
pair solve_quadratic (float a, float b, float c);
```

When you are ready to return from `solve_quadratic`, use:

```
pair p;
p.x1 = x1;
p.x2 = x2;
return p;
```

And change where you use it:

```
// if (scanf ("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c) == 1)
//                                      ^^^ That is not correct.
if (scanf ("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c) == 3)
{
    pair p = solve_quadratic(a,b,c);
    printf("Square roots of this quadratic are: %f %f \n", p.x1. p.x2);
}
```